# Escaping bash code sequence inside a powershell script

Tags: linux, bash, powershell

I need to connect from PowerShell to a Linux machine, get some folders that match a name and afterwards delete them (if you're asking why, cleanup for a test environment).

To accomplish this, I'm using the SSH.NET library (details [here](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/SSH_from_PowerShell_using_the_SSH.NET_library)) and my script looks like this so far:

```
New-SshSession -ComputerName UbuntuMachine -Username root -Password test1234
Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Command {\
        cd /dev;\
        shopt -s nullglob;\
        backupsToDelete=(Nostalgia*);\
        printf "%s\n" "${backupsToDelete[@]}";\
        for i in "${backupsToDelete[@]}"\
        do\
            printf $i\
        done}
```

Everything works fine until I reach the point where I need to loop through my `backupsToDelete` array. It seems that for some reason, PowerShell is treating the `for` loop as it's own statement and not a bash one, everything resulting in an error:

```
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CleanupLinux.ps1:7 char:6
+         for i in "${backupsToDelete[@]}"\
+            ~
Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingOpenParenthesisAfterKeyword
```

Is there any way to tell PowerShell to not execute these kind of statements as it's own? Or maybe a different approach?

Comment: `-Command` want `string` not `ScriptBlock`. Yes, `ScriptBlock` can be converted to `string` automatically, but first it have to be parsed using PowerShell syntax rules.

Answer (score 0):

```
$command = "@
{\
cd /dev;\
shopt -s nullglob;\
backupsToDelete=(Nostalgia*);\
printf "%s\n" "${backupsToDelete[@]}";\
for i in "${backupsToDelete[@]}"\
do\
   printf $i\
done}
@"

New-SshSession -ComputerName UbuntuMachine -Username root -Password test1234
Invoke-SshCommand -InvokeOnAll -Command $command
```

try like so.

Comment: Is that supposed to be PowerShell here-string?

Comment: yeah, thats exactly it.

Comment: It use `@"<new line>` and `<new line>"@` as delimiters.

Comment: Not getting errors in PowerShell, but the bash syntax seems to be incorrect. It's complaining about '\r' now.